# Remove duplicates from Lake Formation Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-lake-formation

I've a glue job that reads from a Kinesis stream and stores the data on a governed table on lake formation.

The issue comes that I have duplicated data. Let's say the user changed is address and now I have two records for the same user when I just want the last one.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: if the data is stored in S3, then this becomes difficult unless you have a de-duplication job running and loading the latest data to a latest only table. At the most what you can do now is to join the existing table with the incoming stream and write the latest record to a different table. Another possible way is to use the `delta lake`.

Comment: Another thing you can do is to de-dup when you are reading the data back.